# What these layouts are

Tags: java, layout

I don't know what these layouts are.

1. First picture how to make this group of buttons to be on the right of the TextArea(please post some code sample, thank you)
2. How to make this JTextArea so big firts picture.
3. Second picture how to make these empty fields on the left and on the right of panel.
4. Second picture: how to get that size of JTextArea and JTextField.

Other ones are easy so I don't ask about them

[First http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/8504/84871015.png](http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/8504/84871015.png)

[Second http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/3372/93341349.png](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/3372/93341349.png)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to tell exactly what layout is used just from looking at a picture because you can achieve these in multiple different ways. This is especially true if you consider resizing behaviour.

However I suspect the answers are:

1. Proably a GridLayout (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) contained within a BorderLayout
2. Probably using a BorderLayout or a GridLayout - both of these will expand the text areas to fill the relevant zones of the screen.
3. Probably a BorderLayout, using the East and West panels for the textfields.
4. Again probably a Borderlayout, with the textfield in the bottom panel.

Although you can clearly do all these with the standard layout managers, if I wanted to replicate these layouts then I'd probably use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) which is a very flexible, general purpose layout manager.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is more than one way to achieve these layouts, I would guess that you are looking at [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html), the most flexible but also the hardest of them all to get right.

Your first picture has six rows and four columns. Fields occupy all columns in the first three rows; text area occupies the first column in rows four through six; buttons occupy individual cells.

Your second picture has four rows and six columns. Text areas are one column by three rows, text field is one row by six columns, and buttons are one cell each.

Oracle offers a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) on it - if you work through their examples, you should be able to make your own layouts that look like the ones in your pictures.

Comment: Is there any way to not use GridBag? I have problems with this one(in practice, in theory it works great).

Comment: @RobertKilar I'm with you on this one: I remember spending long hours getting the thing to lay out my fields and buttons precisely the way I wanted! There are other ways to get this to work, perhaps with a different resizing behavior, but it would still look fine. Look at mikera's answer for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This `JButtons` are placed by use `GridBagLayout()` I give you some similar example how to do this.

```
controls = new JPanel();
controls.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();
        d.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        d.weightx = 1;
        d.weighty = 1;
        seven = new JButton("7");
        buttonsList.add(seven);
        d.gridx = 0;
        d.gridy = 2;
        d.insets = new Insets(0, 4, 4, 4);
        controls.add(seven, d);

        eight = new JButton("8");
        buttonsList.add(eight);
        d.gridx = 1;
        d.gridy = 2;
        d.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 4, 4);
        controls.add(eight, d);

        nine = new JButton("9");
        buttonsList.add(nine);
        d.gridx = 2;
        d.gridy = 2;
        d.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 4, 4);
        controls.add(nine, d);

        plus = new JButton("+");
        buttonsList.add(plus);
        d.gridx = 3;
        d.gridy = 2;
        controls.add(plus, d);

        four = new JButton("4");
        buttonsList.add(four);
        d.gridx = 0;
        d.gridy = 3;
        d.insets = new Insets(0, 4, 0, 4);
        controls.add(four, d);
```